# Android Studio not showing release files

Tags: android, file, google-maps, android-studio, release

Using:

> Android Studio 2.2
>   Build #AI-145.3276617, built on September 15, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 x86_64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

I had a problem using google maps release key (my app was not showing the map en release mode). At beginning I thought I missed copy the API_KEY for release, so I opened the files generated by Android Studio: google_maps_api.xml but the surprise was that I had already change them, I mean, one API_KEY for debug and one for release, so I got a little confused.

This is how my project looks like in Android mode:
[image: Project file tree in Android mode]

This snippet of code was generated by Android Studio in my AndroidManifest:
[image]

After running the app in release mode I got this error:
[image]

At this point, like I said I was confusing because I thought that the API_KEY that I used in the file `google_maps_api.xml` was the release one... but not.
After digging in files I found that I had a 3rd file with same name but in /release/res/values/ path **but Android Studio doesn't show it**

At the end I just copied manually the API key value to file /release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

So the questions:
**am I missing some configuration in Android Studio to get it show me release files or is it a bug?**
**shouldn't Android Studio replace the files from main to release automatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add you API_KEY at the end of your manifest?

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDHG0bSP0pJB4U-sqAcsgldjtwywXUOYfMlqE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[Here is the complete instruction on how to add the Key in order to use Google Map inside your application](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=fr)

Comment: Nop, I'm using the standard or new configuration way given from AS or google (no idea). the "value" is set in a separated file. Im going to add this to the question. thx.

Comment: Done, look at the question again please

Comment: I'm not using that way so I'm not sure i'll be useful then... But it looks like you forgot to replace their temporary value for the API_KEY... Did you paste the resulted key that the website gave you : **Copy the resulting API key, go back to Android Studio, and paste the API key into the <string> element in the google_maps_api.xml file.**

Comment: Yeah I did it manually, but was so annoying losing like 2 hours looking for an error generated by something that Android Studio should show you (the release files, like it does with debug or main files)

Comment: And you did enable the key by clicking the button "Get A Key" and select your application name? It weird, this use to be simple before haha

Comment: Yeah, I like using the "new" or the "recommended" things but some times you got problems like this one hahaha

Comment: Did you fixed it? :/ You can add your answer in the comment I think... Thanks for the accepted answer :D

Comment: No :/ but you were the only one that gave me a light to find the error. Its a bug on AS. It's not showing release files some times.

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted this answer as it don't answer the question, I also don't see that release file, I made release build and found bug... So there is not way to see release resources normally in android studio ? Why it is hidden ?